# Enable different elements for different webform-content type

Tags: webforms

The Webform module has a setting page (admin/settings/webform) that enables you to select which content type you want to act as a "webform".
You can also select which elements show up in the form, but this is a global setting.
Is there any way that we can select different elements for different webform-content types?

Comment: You'll need to provide Drupal and Webform versions.  Also, no offence, but with an acceptance rate of 30% you may be lucky to get an answer =\

Comment: Luca, Welcome to Drupal Answers. People answering questions on this site gain reputation and privileges by answering questions and other services that help the site.  If you receive an good answer, thank the answerer by checking the up triangle.  If you accept the answer as correct, click the check mark.

Comment: Chapabu, Please consider a more positive approach.